# How can I have 2 separate lines in SVG tag, one animating after the other?

Tags: html, svg, path

I have an SVG tag in my html files, and I have co-ordinates that I want to basically animate one path, and when it finishes, animate the second. But both paths animate starting at the same time, and I'm not sure why.

I've tried putting the co-ordinates in the path, with M to move then L to make the line, then another M which I thought would start the 2nd path, etc.

Here is my path:

```
<defs>
<path id="path1" d="M1400 1520 L1260 1480 M1280 480 L1110 460 L1060 260 L1180 240 " />
<mask id="mask1"><use class="mask" xlink:href="#path1"></mask>
</defs>
<use class="paths" xlink:href="#path1" mask="url(#mask1)" />
```

and here is .css to animate:

```
.paths {
  fill: none;
  stroke: black;
  stroke-dasharray: 12;
  stroke-width: 5;
  stroke-linejoin: round;
}

.mask {
  fill: none;
  stroke: white;
  stroke-width: 10;
  stroke-dasharray: 1000;
  stroke-dashoffset: 1000;
  animation: dash 5s linear alternate infinite;
}

/* does not work in IE, need JS to animate there */
@keyframes dash {
  from {
    stroke-dashoffset: 1000;
  }
  to {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  }
}
```

...as you can see the 1st path draws just 1 line, then I would like to move to the start of the 2nd line (M1280) but this starts animating as soon as the line at M1400 for some reason

Comment: Animating how? You've not shown that. Please edit your question to contain a [mcve]

Comment: Ok I edited my OP to show how it animates

Answer (score 1):

To animate two lines separately, you need to divide the common path into two paths:

```
<path id="path1" fill="none" stroke="black"  d="M1400 1520 L1260 1480" /> 
<path id="path2" fill="none" stroke="red" d="M1280 480 L1110 460 L1060 260 L1180 240" />
```

To get the lines in view, I used the command `transform = "translate (x y)"`
You can specify your coordinates `X` `Y` for positioning depending on your needs.

To animate line drawing, the `stroke-dashoffset` attribute is used.

For `id = "path1"` the length of the line is `148px`
For `id = "path2"` the length of the line is `499px`

The animation of the second line begins after the end of the animation of the first line `begin ="an1.end"`

```html
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
      width="1800" height="1800" viewBox="0 0 1800 1800">

 <path id="path1" fill="none" stroke="black" stroke-width="5"
    transform="translate(-1100 -1200)"
 stroke-dashoffset="148"
 stroke-dasharray="148 148"  
    d="M1400 1520 L1260 1480" >
 <animate id="an1"
   attributeName="stroke-dashoffset"
   begin="0s;an2.end"
   dur="2s"
   values="148;0;148"
   fill="freeze" />
</path> 

 <path id="path2" fill="none" stroke="red" stroke-width="5"
     transform="translate(-1000 -220)"
  stroke-dashoffset="499"
  stroke-dasharray="499 499" 
  d="M1280 480 L1110 460 L1060 260 L1180 240" >
   <animate id="an2"
     attributeName="stroke-dashoffset"
  begin="an1.end"
  dur="2s"values="499;0;499"
  from="499"
  to="0"
  fill="freeze" />
</path> 


</svg>
```

### CSS animation

```css
#path1 {
fill:none;
stroke:black;
stroke-width: 5;
stroke-linejoin: round;
stroke-dashoffset:148;
stroke-dasharray:148;
animation: dash1 1.5s linear alternate infinite;
}

@keyframes dash1 {
  from {
    stroke-dashoffset: 148;
  }
  to {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  }
} 


#path2 {
fill:none;
stroke:red;
stroke-width: 5;
stroke-linejoin: round;
stroke-dashoffset:499;
stroke-dasharray:499;
animation: dash2 3s linear alternate infinite;
animation-delay:3s;
}
@keyframes dash2 {
  from {
    stroke-dashoffset: 499;
  }
  to {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
      width="1800" height="1800" viewBox="0 0 1800 1800">

 <path id="path1" transform="translate(-1100 -1200)" d="M1400 1520 L1260 1480" >
 </path> 

 <path id="path2"  transform="translate(-1000 -220)"
   d="M1280 480 L1110 460 L1060 260 L1180 240" >
 </path> 
</svg>
```

Comment: how come you have 2 svg elements? I assume the top 1 is the 1 to use? Also, is there a way for the 1st path to not retreat before the 2nd path starts? In other words, 1st path animates forward, then 2nd path animates forward, then 2nd path retreats, then 1st path retreats.

Comment: @E.D. To animate two lines separately, you need to divide the common path into two paths: While the line consists of two paths, it will be drawn simultaneously in two places.